# Version of SQLite used in Android?

Tags: database, android, sqlite, schema, migration

What is the version of SQLite used in Android?

Reason: I'm wondering how to handle schema migrations. The newer SQLite versions support an "ALTER TABLE" SQL command which would save me having to copy data, drop the table, recreate table and re-insert data.

Comment: You still might want to copy-drop-recreate-reinsert; SQLite's ALTER TABLE isn't very full-featured.

Comment: Please choose the correct answer, 3.4.0 is not right

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the version of Android you're running though? I might indeed have SQLite 3.4.x on my old myTouch running 1.6 OR I might have a higher version on my new G2 running 2.2. The true answer is to check for your particular handset.

Comment: 1.0.0 of android.arch.persistence:db and android.arch.persistence:db-framework shipped a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 535):

Here is a link to the official docs which include the main points in this answer: [android.database.sqlite package-level javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

Kotlin code to get framework SQLite version (tip: just stick a breakpoint in your Activity `onCreate()` and use this code in `Evaluate Expression...`):

```
val version = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.create(null).use {
    android.database.DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(it, "SELECT sqlite_version()", null)
};
"Framework (API ${android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}) SQLite version: $version".also { println(it) }
```

Using the emulators (note, SQLite version on actual devices will be ***at least*** that specified):

| API level* | [Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) | Name | [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 15 | V | [3.42.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_42_0.html) | Developer Preview 1 |
| 34 | 14 | U | [3.39.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_39_2.html) | [RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#rjoin) |
| [33](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/33/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html) | 13 | T | [3.32.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_32_2.html) |  |
| 32 | 12L | Sv2 | [3.32.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_32_2.html) |  |
| 31 | 12 | S | [3.32.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_32_2.html) |  |
| [30](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/30/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html) | 11 | R | [3.28.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_28_0.html) | [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) |
| [29](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html) | 10 | Q | [3.22.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_22_0.html) |  |
| [28](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/28/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite) | 9 | Pie | [3.22.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_22_0.html) |  |
| [27](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/27/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite) | 8.1 | Oreo | 3.19.4 | see [3.19.3](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_19_3.html) and [version control check-ins](https://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?n=100&r=branch-3.19) because 3.19.4 link does not exist |
| 26 | 8.0 | Oreo | [3.18.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_18_2.html) | O beta versions used [3.18.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_18_0.html) |
| 25 | 7.1.1 | Nougat | [3.9.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_9_2.html) |  |
| [24](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html) | 7.0 | Nougat | [3.9.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_9_2.html) |  |
| 23 | 6.0 | Marshmallow | [3.8.10.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_10_2.html) | M Preview 1 (SDK level 22) used [3.8.10](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_10.html) |
| 22 | 5.1.1 | Lollipop | 3.8.6.1 | see [3.8.6](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_6.html) and [version control check-ins](https://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?c=1581c30c389acb2a&y=a) because 3.8.6.1 link does not exist |
| 21 | 5.0 | Lollipop | [3.8.6](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_6.html) |  |
| 20 | 4.4W.2 | Android Wear | unknown | no emulator available, but probably either 3.7.11 or 3.8.4.3 |
| 19 | 4.4 | KitKat | [3.7.11](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) |  |
| 18 | 4.3 | Jelly Bean | [3.7.11](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) |  |
| 17 | 4.2 | Jelly Bean | [3.7.11](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) |  |
| [16](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/16/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html)** | 4.1 | Jelly Bean | [3.7.11](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) |  |
| 15 | 4.0.3 | Ice Cream Sandwich | [3.7.4](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_4.html) |  |
| [14](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html)** | 4.0 | Ice Cream Sandwich | [3.7.4](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_4.html) |  |
| 13 | 3.2 | Honeycomb | [3.7.4](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_4.html) |  |
| 12 | 3.1 | Honeycomb | [3.7.4](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_4.html) |  |
| [11](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html)** | 3.0 | Honeycomb | [3.7.4](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_4.html) |  |
| 10 | 2.3.3 | Gingerbread | [3.6.22](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_6_22.html) |  |
| 9 | 2.3.1 | Gingerbread | [3.6.22](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_6_22.html) |  |
| [8](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/8/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html)** | 2.2 | Froyo | [3.6.22](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_6_22.html) |  |
| 7 | 2.1 | Eclair | [3.5.9](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_5_9.html) |  |
| 4 | 1.6 | Donut | [3.5.9](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_5_9.html) |  |
| [3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/3/changes/pkg_android.database.sqlite.html)** | 1.5 | Cupcake | [3.5.9](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_5_9.html) |  |

* Android API level links show where the [android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) package has changed. Where there is no link (e.g. API level 17), indicates no changes to that package.

** Broken SDK link, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154744900)

Note: if you want your app to use the same version of SQLite across all Android versions, consider using Requery's [3rd party SQLite support library](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) or [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) (if you also want encryption).

Comment: /system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found
This is on rooted Android 4.0.2 device

Comment: Thanks mark. I'm confused a bit. While development how can i make sure my sqlite version remain consistent across all devices? i mean does `targetSdkVersion` or `buildTarget` has any influence on that?

Answer (score 60):

Although the documentation gives 3.4.0 as reference number, if you execute the following sql, you'll notice that there is a much higher number of SQlite installed:

```
Cursor cursor = SQLiteDatabase.create(null).rawQuery("select sqlite_version() AS sqlite_version", null);
String sqliteVersion = "";
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
   sqliteVersion += cursor.getString(0);
}
```

This is just a piece of quick, dirty code to retrieve the sqlite version. For instance on a HTC Hero with Android 2.1, I get: **3.5.9**.

On my Nexus One with Android 2.2, I even get **3.6.22**.

Comment: I imagine 3.4.0 is given as a minimum version # - for portability you probably shouldn't assume its a higher version unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Comment: sure, you're right. But if you have to use some advanced features which may improve performance on higher SQLite versions, you may use the code to query and eventually switch the kind of query depending on the deployed version :)

Comment: My Droid with a custom 2.2 ROM also reports 3.6.22

Comment: My Epic with pre-release 2.2 says 3.6.23 -- the numbers seem to be inching upwards.

Comment: Nexus 7 with Android 4.2, gives 3.7.11

Comment: For quick check this can be done in one expression with `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(openOrCreate...)` in the Android Studio Evaluate window.

Answer (score 25):

```
$ adb shell sqlite3 --version 
3.5.9
```

Same on ADP1 1.6 & 2.1 emulator.

Comment: It gives me: sqlite3: permission denied

Comment: Worked fine for me. I opened cmd prompt and navigated to android folder, where adb.exe was located. Then I typed in the two commands

Comment: gives "/system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found" on the Nexus 4 KitKat.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142003176

Answer (score 7):

A short overview of the Andorid APIs and the supported SQLite versions.

[image]

The overview is from the link in Mark's answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Room you can query

SELECT sqlite_version()

RG