# what are Datatypes in SQLite supporting android

Tags: android, sqlite, types

Can anyone please tell me the LIST OF DATATYPES in SQLITE supporting ANDROID.

I want to confirm about TIME and DATE datatypes.

Answer (score 43):

Here is a [list](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) of SQLite's data types

TIME and DATE are supported [indirectly](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: I think date and time can both only been inserted as string

Comment: Or Using UNIX timestamp and save them as INTEGER, also BOOLEAN is stored as INTEGER 0 or 1

Answer (score 32):

As said at [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> - **NULL**. The value is a NULL value.
> - **INTEGER**. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
> - **REAL**. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
> - **TEXT**. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
> - **BLOB**. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

And for TIME and DATE storage the following is stated:

> **Date and Time Datatype**
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check the Sqlite3 version for each android API version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/737636

I don't think that this is the full list of versions and I think that also OEM can change the SQLite's version installed inside.

Anyway, if you take a quick look you can see that the base version is 3.x

This is the list of supported datatypes by SQLite3 (the same used inside android): http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

and here you are :)