# I'm new in Android. When I'm using this code. My Emulator is getting "Unfortunately Myapp has stopped."

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, import

I'm new in Android. When I'm using this code. My Emulator is getting "Unfortunately Myapp has stopped." 
 In this code I'm trying to add some sort of common person's details in Sqlite and also selecting and deleting from Sqlite.
This is my XML File that I'm using it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name:"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name:"
        android:id="@+id/textlastname" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editlastname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender:"
        android:id="@+id/textgender" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editgender"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:id="@+id/textage" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address:"
        android:id="@+id/textaddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editaddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New Person"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java File that I'm using it.

```
    package com.example.gaurang.myhomes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "students";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "pName";
    public static final String COL_LAST = "pLast";
    public static final String COL_GENDER = "pGender";
    public static final String COL_AGE = "pAge";
    public static final String COL_ADDRESS = "pAddress";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "pDate";
    private static final String STRING_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"             (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +COL_NAME+" TEXT, "+COL_LAST+" TEXT, "+COL_GENDER+" TEXT,     "+COL_AGE+" TEXT, "+COL_ADDRESS+" TEXT, "+COL_DATE+" DATE);";

    public MyDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(STRING_CREATE);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(6);
        cv.put(COL_NAME, "New Entry");
        cv.put(COL_LAST, "New Entry");
        cv.put(COL_GENDER, "New Entry");
        cv.put(COL_AGE, "New Entry");
        cv.put(COL_ADDRESS, "New Entry");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd     HH:mm:ss");
        cv.put(COL_DATE, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)         {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    EditText mText;
    EditText mLast;
    EditText mGender;
    EditText mAge;
    EditText mAddress;
    Button mAdd;
    ListView mList;

    MyDbHelper mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    Cursor mCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        mLast = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editlastname);
        mGender = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editgender);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editage);
        mAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editaddress);
        mAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        mAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mHelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {"_id",     MyDbHelper.COL_NAME,MyDbHelper.COL_LAST,MyDbHelper.COL_GENDER,MyDbHelper.COL_AGE    ,MyDbHelper.COL_ADDRESS, MyDbHelper.COL_DATE};
        mCursor = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,     null, null, null, null);
        String[] headers = new String[]     {MyDbHelper.COL_NAME,MyDbHelper.COL_LAST,MyDbHelper.COL_GENDER,MyDbHelper.COL_AG    E,MyDbHelper.COL_ADDRESS, MyDbHelper.COL_DATE};
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,     android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                mCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1,     android.R.id.text2});
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDb.close();
        mCursor.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(6);
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_NAME, mText.getText().toString());
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_LAST, mLast.getText().toString());
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_GENDER, mGender.getText().toString());
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_AGE, mAge.getText().toString());
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_ADDRESS, mAddress.getText().toString());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd     HH:mm:ss");
        cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_DATE, dateFormat.format(new Date())); //Insert     'now' as the date
        mDb.insert(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        mCursor.requery();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mText.setText(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,     long id) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String rowId = mCursor.getString(0); //Column 0 of the cursor is the     id
        mDb.delete(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{rowId});
        mCursor.requery();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the log file - there should be an exception there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "+COL_AGE+" TEXT, "+COL_ADDRESS+" TEXT, "+COL_DATE+" DATE);";
```

SQL Lite on Android does not support DATE columns **directly**. You can use a TEXT column or an INTEGER column to store it.

For additional details: [what are Datatypes in SQLite supporting android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830372/274340)