# Enable foreign keys on Sqlite3 version 3.5.9

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm trying to enable foreign keys on a sqlite3 database doing this:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

But it doen't work.

How can I do it?

**Note: the database is on an Android device.**

Thanks.

Comment: This statement only works since sqlite version 3.6.19.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 supports foreign keys only as of version 3.6.19 http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

**UPDATE**

[Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)