# SQLite3 FTS4, MATCH and Android

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

Is SQLite3 FTS4-enabled in the Android build?

Comment: also here is a good example how to work with fts db
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29926430

Answer (score 17, accepted):

no, only FTS3 look here => [The enhancements for FTS4 were added with SQLite version 3.7.4 on 2010-12-08](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_1) ...and... [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android/4377116#4377116)

EDIT (2011-10-25):

since API >= 11 (aka Honeycomb and ICS) FTS4 should be enabled [again see: Version of SQLite used in Android? for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android/4377116#4377116)