# Most efficient way to store and search through a large number of strings

Tags: java, android

I have a large number of strings used in my Android application that are broken down into three categories: 1 word strings, 2 word strings, 3 word strings. I need to be able to search through these three lists of strings quickly looking for matches to a given key and returning a third value associated to these strings.

For instance if I'm looking for the key `"New York"` and my list is:

```
New York, test1
New Jersey, test2
Colorado, test3
Arkansas, test4
New York, test5
```

A search would return the strings: `test1 and test5`

What is the best way to store these strings that searching for matches is fastest on an android phone?

The options I thought of so far were: database, xml, csv. Are there any other options and what would be the best choice for this situation?

Edit:
What if I wanted to preserve an order of the items so they could be moved up or down on the list, i know Hashmap is un-ordered. Would an arraylist work?

Comment: definitely skip xml. xml and speed do not generally get used in the same sentence in anything other than a negative sense. consider using the native sqlite facilities (e.g. database).

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into that, I don't have much sql or sqlite experience but I can learn

Comment: Regarding SQLite: There is a full-text-search extension that could be useful http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339022/sqlite3-fts4-match-and-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store them as a Map between key and list of values, and use the inbuilt SQLLite database within Android to persist them permanently there?

So essentially, instead of your list, you would have:

```
New York: [test1, test5]
New Jersey: test2
Colorado: test3
Arkansas: test4
```

Keeping New York unique, you will get the results much faster. In traditional DB sense, it will be the foreign key to your values.

Answer (score 1):

The best and fastes way is to use a database. Use SQLite to store and seearch data in your database.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 1):

Parse your file, split each line using `,` as a delimiter. Create hash table (one of implentations of `java.util.Map`) and put the parsed results there, so that `New York` is a key and `test1`, `test5` etc are values stored in list:

`Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`

Now you have direct access to this table and can always find mapping of any city.

Comment: When you say parse my file, do you mean that I should store the lists of strings in say a csv file, and then every time I start up the application on my phone load the lists from the files into the hash table? Couldn't that take a large amount of time every time the app is launched?