# android - Cursor returning wrong values

Tags: android

I'm querying some products in SQLite database, but same base in 2 differents android's versions return differents values.

Select result in database.db3 using SQLite Expert:

[image: result]

I create this code after select, to test:

```
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                log("CDPROD:" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CDPROD")));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Log Result in android 2.2:

```
09-26 14:30:08.947: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000211934
09-26 14:30:08.967: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000211944
09-26 14:30:08.967: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000212020
09-26 14:30:08.967: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000212124
09-26 14:30:08.967: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000214280
09-26 14:30:08.967: INFO/LOGG(20497): CDPROD:000000000000212886
```

Log Result in android 2.1:

```
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:211934
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:211944
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:212020
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:212124
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:214280
09-26 14:18:16.772: INFO/LOGG(1039): CDPROD:212886
```

This is a bug in Android??

Ty

Comment: What's the data type of the `CRPOD` column?

Comment: What type affinity is set for that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use as the column type `text` not `string` or `varchar` when you create your `SQLiteTables`. It seems that if you put `string` it will `trim` your leading `zeros`. Also see [SQLite Data Types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

**EDIT:** According to this [answer: Versions of SQLite in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android/4377116#4377116), they have diffrent `SQLite versions`.

Comment: Ok.But why these differences in android versions?