# which sqlite version is compatible for android 2.2 froyo

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently, my sqlite version isn't compatible for Android 2.2 froyo (Samsung galaxy ace) and encountering error message. Please let me know which sqlite version I need to use for Android 2.2 froyo.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {      

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);          
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }       
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the emulators:

```
3-1.5-Cupcake: 3.5.9
4-1.6-Donut: 3.5.9
7-2.1-Eclair: 3.5.9
8-2.2-Froyo: 3.6.22
9-2.3.1-Gingerbread: 3.6.22
10-2.3.3-Gingerbread: 3.6.22
11-3.0-Honeycomb: 3.7.4
12-3.1-Honeycomb: 3.7.4
13-3.2-Honeycomb: 3.7.4
```

Copy from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android/4377116#4377116) .