# no such module: fts4aux- Error while querying sqlite virtual table created using fts4aux

Tags: android, sqlite, fts4

I am trying to collect the words and built a set from fts4aux table to feed a AutocCompleteTextView. But having issues accessing the virtual table created using fts4aux

I have a virtual table 'ProductVirtual'.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ProductVirtual USING fts4(name, company)
```

From this i have created a fts4aux table called 'product_terms'.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE product_terms USING fts4aux(ProductVirtual)
```

Here is my query

> select term from product_terms

When i run this query against the sqlite db from a db console, i am able to retrieve the result.

But when i use the same query from my android app it throws the following error

> I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(26555): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no
>   such module:  fts4aux,
>   db=/data/data/com.product/databases/product_device.db

At the same time i am able to query the fts4 virtual table from the android app 
without problem. So, i am sure fts4 is enabled.

But only problem is using the 'fts4aux' table. How do i overcome this? Do i have 
to enable 'fts4aux' separately somewhere?

please post your thoughts. thanks!

Comment: Does your app run with at least 3.7.6? `select sqlite_version();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, here is the sqlite version that i run **3.7.12.1**

Comment: I've never heard of an [Android with that version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android#4377116); which device and OS version is this?

Answer (score 0):

Using fts4aux requires SQLite 3.7.6 or later, and as shown in [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android#4377116), this requires Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean), or some specific device where the vendor updated to a newer SQLite version.