# Edited; Android app SQLite exceptions different emulators

Tags: java, android

Edited;

My application works fine in the android emulator. Now i've installed the .apk in "Bluestacks", a client for running android apps on your pc, and on the android-x86 VM. Both crash or restart, the moment i press the button to go to the next activity.

After making sure only the main activity has its installed icon shown, I start the application, and as soon as I press a button linked to an intent to the next activity, the main activity restarts in bluestacks, and gives a crash error in the VM.

This behaviour isn't shown on the android emulator. What could be the reason for this?

AndroidManifest:

```
....
<application
    android:name="MainApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.NewAuditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_index" >
       <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
....
```

In the main activity i do this;

```
public void viewNewAudits(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewAuditActivity.class);
    TextView auditorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainViewAuditor);
    intent.putExtra("auditor", auditorView.getText());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The button clicked in the xml view correctly calls the onclick:"viewNewAudits" method.

What could be the reason for the application not to continue to the next activity? As the android emulator runs the app, i can't find out what error/exception could be the reason for the crash.

Edit:

My search for logs on the VBox VM made me experiment some with the adb logcat command. I've found some logs from the VM and it gives an SQLite exception. This makes sense because in the second activity I start intantiating my DB and querymanager. Weird thing is though, that the sqliteexception is a syntax error. Is there any way in which a SQLite syntax would be different on another emulator? short piece of logcat log:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2039): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=..../.activ
ities.NewAuditActivity (has extras) }
I/Database( 2797): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error

D/AndroidRuntime( 2797): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2797): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb
5891290)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2797): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{.....activities.NewAuditActivity}: androi
d.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: IN
SERT INTO Criteria (auditTemplateId, code, requirement, MOE, description) VALUES
('145', '.A.25(a)', 'Facility, size and segregation', '1.8-2.7 exhibit 5-2.3', ...... *more of the same inserts with a lot of comma's
```

Comment: I would suggest your app on android emulator or real device.. or you would end up spending time on bugs of third party tools.. if it worked fine on emulator then there could be bug in the Bluestacks client that you are using... try on real device...

Comment: That would in fact be a possible answer to my question, is the android emulator as close to the actual device as possible? I thought it might be the android emulator being buggy as sometimes -out of the blue- it refuses to run any app at all, and new device have to be created to continue testing..

As I don't own an android device, for now i'm forced to use emulators.

But can I assume that you actually looked at the code and didn't see something wrong wih it? Because that's helpful to me already, that could 've been your answer

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. and since it is working fine on android emulator so you can assume that the bug is in the Bluestacks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..*sigh*..

It seems like the other emulator contained a slightly older version of android, which had no influence on the code, but used a slightly older version of the SQLite DB. This resulted in an error as i tried to fill the db with a compoound insert query. This makes my problem the same as the one here: [SQLite error on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518653/sqlite-error-on-insert?lq=1)

Additional information: This video shows very clear how to setup the android-x86 project on virtualbox as an alternative to the existing emulator: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFCan01I6QQ

To be able to check the logs of this device, you can use adb as shown in the video, but this time you use: 'adb -s <*Emulator serial number*> logcat'. This prints the complete logcat log to the command line.

As for Bluestacks. This client does not show any kind of error, it just resets the application flawlessly without any notice. That might be something to keep in mind while using this software.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest your app on android emulator or real device.. or you would end up spending time on bugs of third party tools.. if it worked fine on emulator then there could be bug in the Bluestacks client that you are using... try on real device...

Emulator helps a lot when you don't have the device for each developer. Emulator can be used to check the basic UI and the flow of the application.

A real device should be used for checking the pixel perfect UI, performance, location based feature, network connectivity based feature. etc..

So testing on a real device before each release of an feature is important.

EDIT1: Following link also has very interesting discussion on emulator vs real device:

[Android Emulator vs Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115413/android-emulator-vs-real-device)

EDIT2: In NewAuditActivity class are you handling the case if the value of `auditor` in `intent extra` is `null` or `empty string`?

Comment: Thank you Praful, it isn't just a bluestacks bug though, there has to be something wrong with the application, as it crashes an Android VM too.

As stated in the post you linked, apparently there are things you can get away with in the android emulator, that crash other devices.

edit; PS; Sorry, can't upvote, my rep is too low -_-

Comment: Ah, good thinking, but yes, that is something that is taken care of. So that cannot be the problem.

Posting logcat logs is a problem too because the crash happens in virtual box, setup as shown in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFCan01I6QQ

Comment: development of android app is very difficult without the logcat... so I would suggest you to figure out how to get logcat logs from virtual box.. again i would suggest you to try it on real device...

Comment: I have edited the post Praful, took me long enough, but i managed to access the device's Logcat! Also, thank you for taking the time to try and help me Praful :)

Comment: I would request you to post the process to get the logs (whenever you have some free time) so that other people can also benefit from that knowledge :-)...