# what versions of SQLite is used in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Im developing a android application for a **tablet and mobiles**

The application perform some DB operations (saving,deleting,etc in DB)

My configuration details are **minimum sdk is 8 and target sdk is 17**

Here i did not know what **sqllite version** is used in android from **version 8 to latest version.**

It is very usefull to db compatibility in my project

So please provid the details where i get these details

So please all are welcome to give their ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLite 3.6.22:`

- API 8 - 2.2 - Froyo

`SQLite 3.7.11:`

- API 17 - 4.2 - Jelly Bean

Full article you can find here:

- [`Version of SQLite used in
  Android?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)