# Is it possible to create a database and to push it to my android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to do the following,

I want to create a sqlite database in my java swing application and to load it with all data that I will need.
After that I want to push this database to my Android App.

Is it possible with no so much trouble?

I mean, can I simply to create this database and after that only push it to my Android App and open it calling its name. For example "MySQLite.bd".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why don't you just try if it works?

Comment: do you have a server with a db?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it easily. Once you are ready with your SQLite database, you can load that pre-filled database in your android app.

Check following link for detailed steps for this :

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I decided to follow the approach above, my only question is, is it really necessary create in all my sqlite tables the "_id" field?

Comment: @Levi, actually you can omit that part. You simply need to create sqlite database and just follow the steps : 
- check database (if its exists or not?)
- if db not exists then create is -> using Copying database (like file copy of java) 
- after creating it open it and you will get the db object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just make sure [your Android's SQLite engine version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) is compatible with the SQLite DB you're using in your Swing application.

Comment: SQLite Manager?.. He is using a java swing app

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't read that, but actually doesn't matter. He just have to make sure the DB he creates is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create such a db yes!

See [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) on how to code in android in order to use the DB.

**Edit:** one more [link](http://wuxuesong.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/using-pre-existing-sqlite-database-in-android-app/) mentioning also the problem with large external DBs.