# SQLite - reading and writing in the same time without WAL mode

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my application I do multi-threads to perform different operations in the background. I know that I can solve it by making the Data-base `SingleTon` and use the `WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING` privilege, but this only supported from `API 16` and higher. I have a lot of users that use lower APIs.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

According to the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html):

> *Beginning with version 3.7.0, a new "Write-Ahead Log" option (hereafter referred to as "WAL") is available.*

Before that, SQLite used an exclusive locking mechanism as described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#locking).

Problem is, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/813951), SQLite v3.7.x was added to Android in Honeycomb.

Comment: What is your advice? Should I use the WAL and prevent the less API or what?

Comment: I Have solved it by using the method `enableWriteAheadLog()`. This is enabled starting from API 11. Thank you