# Sort alphabetically and select first row from android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to sort data in my Android Sqlite alphabetically and then choose only the first row for each alphabet. e.g. If the result set consists of Abc, Abd, Abe, Bbc, Bbd I want only Abc, Bbc. 
Is it possible using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for SQLite.

```
SELECT min(column_name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY substr(column_name, 1, 1)
```

The substring syntax may differ on other systems. It groups your data by the first character, then returns the alphabetical minimum of each in the group.

-- edit (1/2)

If you need the entire row, it's probably best to use the results of the above query to find the entire row. Like so:

```
SELECT table_name.*
FROM table_name 
 JOIN 
    (SELECT min(column_name) AS column_name
     FROM table_name
     GROUP BY substr(column_name, 1, 1)) sub_query
 ON table_name.column_name = sub_query.column_name
 GROUP BY column_name
 HAVING table_name.ROWID = min(table_name.ROWID)
```

-- edit (2/2)

Added the last two lines (GROUP BY and HAVING). They are needed to avoid duplicates. If you have duplicate entries for column_name then the one with the lowest ROWID is chosen.

Comment: I don't want minimum , I want EXACTLY one row.

Comment: Just try it. If your dataset is Abc; Abd; Abe; Bbc; Bbd; this query will return Abc; Bbc.

Comment: How to modify this if I want to sort by NAME , but also want to get another column, say CATEGORY ?

Comment: Thanks. I am yet to try this due to some other priorities. Will let you know asap.

Comment: If there are duplicate 'column_name' values then the query will return both. You want the 'first row' in that case?

Comment: Yes. Exactly one row.

Comment: This works fine with MySQL but with SQLite the duplicates are completely removed.

Comment: Not in my tests, give me an example of the data you're having trouble with.

Comment: I observe this problem on 2.3.6 but not on 4.4.2. Which version did you test on?

Comment: I tested on OSX running SQLite 3.7.13. Here you can see an overview of SQLite versions on android platforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android

Comment: Any clues for me to explore further ? Any chance you could test on android emulator/phone having 2.3.6 ? I am at my wit's end :-(