# Getting android Sqlite syntax error running in api 14

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite, android-adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have sequence of database adapter, which dumps default values in to the tables.
It works fine on the devices running on API level 19 to 21. When I tried it in API 14. I'm getting the syntax error.

```
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp﹕ sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.myapp/databases/myappdb
```

Here are my sql lines

```
private static final String DATABASE_INSERT_SEARCH =
"INSERT INTO varngle_word (name, count, type) VALUES" +
                    " ('Kindle', 0, 'item')," +
                    " ('Google', 0, 'site');";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SEARCH);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT_SEARCH);
   }
}
```

Comment: `DATABASE_INSERT_SEARCH` seems to work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1f2be) where is your `DATABASE_CREATE_SEARCH`?

Comment: @Trinimon DATABASE_CREATE_SEARCH is another string to create table. no problem in that. "create table varngle_word (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "name text not null, "
                    + "count int not null, "
                    + "type text not null);";

Comment: I know, but I wondered whether table creation could have an impact on the insert. Meanwhile I found it - see answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this post](http://www.tagwith.com/question_427926_android-sqliteexception-near-syntax-error-while-compiling-insert) multi-values syntax was introduced in [SQLite version 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html): *"Enhance the INSERT syntax to allow multiple rows to be inserted via the VALUES clause. "*.

SQLite version 3.7.11 is only in Android 4.1 and up.

- SQLite version 3.7.11 available with API levels: 19, 18, 17, 16
- SQLite version 3.7.4 available with API levels: 15, 14, 13, 12, 11

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) for more details about [SQLite versions](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

Alternatively you could loop through items and insert row by row or use the following:

```
 INSERT INTO varngle_word (name, count, type) 
 SELECT 'Kindle', 0, 'item'
  UNION
 SELECT 'Google', 0, 'site';
```

See [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/baabd/1).

Comment: Does it supports all version of sqlite?

Comment: `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT ...` is pretty much SQL standard. There is a note on 3.5.3: _"Fix a long-standing bug in INSERT INTO ..."_ but this is not applicable to any SQLite versions used with Android. Take care with 3.8.5: _"Fix a bug ... that caused crashes when doing an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement ..."_.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this syntax to insert multiple rows. It comes after sqlite version 3.7.11, and android 4.0 devices usually comes with sqlite 3.7.4.

see this link ([Insert Error SqLite in Android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000989/insert-error-sqlite-in-android-4-0-3)) for some solutions