# trouble with inserting multiple records?

Tags: android, sqlite

I use sql query to insert data into database, everything work fine if i insert just one record into table,here is my code

**1.**  `setData("insert into table(name,age) values ('john','23')");`

code for insert data above succesful saved in database, but I if i use this code bellow

**2.**    `setData("insert into table(name,age) values ('john','23'),('jane','20'),('mraz','21'),('albert','12'),('josh','23')");`

and methode for insert like this

```
public String setData(String sql){
      ourDatabase.execSQL(sql);
  return "success";
}
```

if i use code no **1**, data successfull inserted
but if i use code no **2** it fail.
here log for code no **2**

```
Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x24b900 when preparing 'insert into table(name,age) values ('john','23'),('jane','20'),('mraz','21'),('albert','12'),('josh','23')'.
```

what wrong with code no **2** ?
if i try use code no **2** in mysqlfront or phpmyadmin without throught android is work fine,and second problem is,if i run in jellybean data succesfull inserted into database,but if i run in gingerbread code no **2** trouble?

Comment: You can find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: Search thuis site and find sqlite specific version requirement and syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple values in insert syntax was [introduced in sqlite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_11).

[Older Androids are running older versions of sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).