# Android SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling INSERT

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert values into table

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static String INSERT_INTO_COUNTRIES = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_COUNTRIES
                + " VALUES";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            final String countries = "('1','Andorra','93','flag_andorra','AND'),
        ('2','Austria','43','flag_flag_austria','AUT')";
        String query = INSERT_INTO_COUNTRIES + countries + ";";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

}
```

And get the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO cardberry_countries VALUES('1','Andorra','93','flag_andorra','AND'),('2','Austria','43','flag_flag_austria','AUT');
```

Error occurs on Android 4.0.4 HTC Sense 3.6.
I tested on multiple devices runnin on Android 4.2 and higher and it works fine.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: it's all about sqlite version ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multi-values syntax was introduced in sqlite version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html)

[Sqlite version 3.7.11 is only in Android 4.1 and up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Split your inserts into separate inserts, one row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be easier to spot if you print out the SQL INSERT string.

But even if you fix the problem, this is still a bad way to go.  You ought to be using `PreparedStatement` to escape and bind variables.  It'll be less error prone.  You'll be safer from SQL injection attacks as an added bonus.