# SQLite Database gives warning automatic index on <table_name>(column) After upgrading Android L

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop, android-logcat

I have upgraded my Nexus 7 with Android 5.0 Lollipop, Before that my application going well with **SQLite Database** but now Whenever I execute any type of query,  It gives me **log cat error** like:

```
12-09 12:37:04.942: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on area(server_id)
12-09 12:37:04.942: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on account(area_id)
12-09 12:37:04.942: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on staff_visit(account_id)
12-09 12:37:04.942: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on ordertab(account_id)
12-09 12:37:04.960: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on area(server_id)
12-09 12:37:04.960: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on account(area_id)
12-09 12:37:04.960: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on staff_visit(account_id)
12-09 12:37:04.960: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on ordertab(account_id)
12-09 12:37:04.978: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on area(server_id)
12-09 12:37:04.978: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on account(area_id)
12-09 12:37:04.978: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on staff_visit(account_id)
12-09 12:37:04.978: E/SQLiteLog(13041): (284) automatic index on ordertab(account_id)
```

So Is it Error of Any Lollipop Mistakes? I think so because i dont have updated my code before and after upgrading this OS.

Comment: BTW auto-index is good improves query performance time

Comment: Its strange though as i have manually created indexes for my search or joins columns but still auto indexes are being created.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Automatic indexing](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#autoindex) was introduced in sqlite 3.7.17. A version of sqlite with this feature was only [included in Android L developer preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android). This is why you get the message only on Lollipop but not earlier. Even if it is logged as an error, it's really just a message.

Basically, the automatic indexing comes into play when you're doing lookups on non-indexed columns. sqlite assumes there's so much data that generating a temporary index is cheaper than raw lookup.

Consider adding explicit, permanent indices for your lookup columns with `CREATE INDEX`. For example, after your `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename(columnname);
```

where you can pick `tablename(columnname)` from the autoindex messages as produced by sqlite.

If you just want the old behavior back, you can disable auto-indexing with

```
PRAGMA automatic_index=off;
```

Comment: Thanks @laalto, If i do nothing then anything going to wrong?

Comment: So which is better way to index them. Is this problematic?

Comment: Add an index for each column you use in `WHERE` unless your workload is heavily insert-based

Comment: Thanks man. Accepted. Now I want to update it but i do not know where to write indexing and for which columns mainly. can you share me any example or help me?

Comment: I'm getting these messages on Views. The underlying tables _do have_ an index on the mentioned columns, but I can't create an index on a view.

Comment: So automatic indexing does reduce the query time and is helpful right?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Depends e.g. on the amount of data and proportion of reads to writes.

Comment: Are automatic indexes temporary?

Comment: I have manually created index on foreign keys columns `reference_num` of my 5 tables after creating tables, but i'm still getting this `log 02-11 23:49:35.588: E/SQLiteLog(20914): (284) automatic index on sqlite_sq_B76A2C00(reference_num)
02-11 23:49:35.588: E/SQLiteLog(20914): (284) automatic index on sqlite_sq_B76A2980(reference_num)
02-11 23:49:35.589: E/SQLiteLog(20914): (284) automatic index on sqlite_sq_B76A2700(reference_num)
02-11 23:49:35.589: E/SQLiteLog(20914): (284) automatic index on sqlite_sq_B76A2480(reference_num)`

Comment: in my query there are 5 joins with group by and aggreagte group_concat. It doesn't have any WHERE clause. Can't Index help on JOINS?

Comment: What I don't understand is why I keep getting these messages although I have created an index on exactly that table column....

Comment: @AntonSack Are you sure your index creation has actually been run?

Comment: I hate it when developers can't understand the meaning of an error log... It stains my logcat output! It should be an Info log or Warning at most...

Comment: @AntonSack I had the same problem as you. It was because I was creating my column as `INTEGER` rather than as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. Give the latter a try, if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This was the top post while i was looking into this problem. Although i have a **C# project** and it might not be relevant for the OP, i thought it might still be helpfull for someone.

For those that wonder why the message keeps appearing, although an index was created explicitly; maybe your query is using a different collation.

I had a table with a text column and a select query with a where statement specifying `where name = @var1 COLLATE NOCASE`. This triggered the warnings, as the index i had created was default collation.

Thus, rewriting either the index, or the create table statement, to specify nocase for that column, made the warning disappear.