# Android is confusing Sqlite View as Table and is trying to Auto-Index it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a view that is incorporated in another view call.

```
CREATE VIEW view_A AS SELECT .... FROM table_Gamma

CREATE VIEW view_B AS SELECT .... FROM view_A
```

In Android 5.0 it's printing out this error

**E/SQLiteLog (284) automatic index on view_A(Col1)**

Since you can't index views in Sqlite, it seems to be thinking view_A is a table, and that it can be indexed, when it's a view.

Note I also tried creating an index on table_Gamma, it did not help.

You can turn off auto-indexing using this Pragma call

```
PRAGMA automatic_index = off;
```

[SQLite Database gives warning automatic index on <table_name>(column) After upgrading Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373344/sqlite-database-gives-warning-automatic-index-on-table-namecolumn-after-upgr)

But it seems to be impractical in that it needs to be called every time SQLiteOpenHelper is used.

Is this a common practice, or is there another place to call to turn off automatic_index?

Answer (score 2):

from this thread
[Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade)

it seems the better way is to override the **onOpen** method in **SQLiteOpenHelper**

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA automatic_index = off;");
        }
    }
```

I still feel it's a bug that Sqlite3 can't differentiate a view withing a view, when calling this error.

Comment: Looking at the query plan if you turn automatic index off it does not use the underlying index. At the same time if you sure a table instead of view, it uses existing index correctly. Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error.
(The only error is that Android labels this warning as an error.)

This message indicates that an automatic index was created successfully.

A table can be used multiple times in a query, so it gets shown with the name under which it is actually used in query, even if this happens to be a view name.