# SQLite gives automatic index warnings, even though the key is the first key in an explicit index

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE LoanEvents (
    Id integer primary key not null, 
    LoanId integer not null default '0', 
    Period integer not null default '0',
    ... more data
    )
```

it has an index defined:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LoanEvents_LoanId_Period
    on LoanEvents(LoanId,Period)
```

I am running a complex query with joins on this table, and I am getting the message:

```
SQLite warning (284): automatic index on LoanEvents(LoanId)
```

Why do I get this warning, when there is already an index with LoanId as the first key?

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the warning, without adding an unnecessary index?

Comment: Show the query? Also read up on how to interpret EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Database gives warning automatic index on <table\_name>(column) After upgrading Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373344/sqlite-database-gives-warning-automatic-index-on-table-namecolumn-after-upgr)

Comment: Plus, having default column values with a unique index is kind of strange. If you tried making that index after populating the table, are you sure it was successful?

Comment: @DourHighArch Not really a duplicate, since OP is already making an index on the relevant column.

Comment: FYI, it is not a duplicate, as I already have a suitable index. Yes, the index exists (I copied the create statement from the schema in the actual database). The query is far to complex (involving about 8 tables) and confidential to post here. If no-one knows the answer off the cuff, I will try to create a non-confidential version and post it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - my query had an error in its JOINs - I accidentally joined the `LoanId` to a string field (with a very similar name to the integer field I meant to join to).

As far as I can see, that meant that SQLite needed a string index on LoanId, rather than the integer index it already had.

The question shown as a possible duplicate, [SQLite Database gives warning automatic index on <table_name>(column) After upgrading Android L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373344/sqlite-database-gives-warning-automatic-index-on-table-namecolumn-after-upgr/27374710) does actually contain a clue in the second answer, which states that the index has to have the same collation as the column that needs it. I guess we can add that it should have the same type too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps: [SQLite Gives Automatic Index Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373344/sqlite-database-gives-warning-automatic-index-on-table-namecolumn-after-upgr)

Disclaimer: I haven't personally tested it yet.

Comment: Considering that post is about **not** having an index on a column and OP's post clearly shows he's making an index on the column in question... you're making the same mistake the guy who flagged this post as a duplicate of that one did.