# Android sqlite version and printf

Tags: android, sqlite, printf, android-sqlite

I've been updating an app for Android 5.0 and have a sqlite database. I've implemented a printf statement. I just found that sqlite 3.8.3 (http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3) was when this was added. I've also found that Android <5.0 ran sqlite versions <3.7.x ([Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)). 
My question is, is there an equivalent to printf in sqlite for previous versions of sqlite for use in statements?

Comment: If it were, it wouldn't have been necessary to add it in 3.8.3.