# How to implement fuzzy search with SQLite's FTS3?

Tags: android, sqlite, search, full-text-search, fts3

I have already [integrated search based on the official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) and
I'm using the following SQLite schema and query:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Search USING FTS3 (
    _id,
    name,
    location
);

select * from Search where name MATCH ?
-- where ? is the user typed exact "query"
-- or if it doesn't have spaces or stars I append a star to search prefix: "query*"
```

I'm wondering how can I extend it? to allow the following:

Say I have some items named:

- My Fancy Item
- My Secret Item
- Item #1
- Your Fancy Item

When the user types `blah` in the search box the search results would show:

- **`my`**

  - **My** Fancy Item
  - **My** Secret Item
- **`mfi`**

  - **M**y **F**ancy **I**tem
- `fan item`, **`fanit`**, `fit`

  - My **Fan**cy **It**em
  - Your **Fan**cy **It**em
- `it`, `item`, **`im`**, `itm`

  - My Fancy **I**te**m**
  - My Secret **I**te**m**
  - **I**te**m** #1
  - Your Fancy **I**te**m**

The results should be ranked based on how good the match is, for example if the letters are farther away they should rank lower than an exact match, like for `mfi`: "My Fancy Item" should rank last and "MFI thingy" should rank first (if there was such an item).

Note: my min SDK is API level 10, which [means it has to work SQLite 3.6.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Similar functionality can be found mostly in IDEs:

- Eclipse: [Open Type](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-open-type.htm) and [Open Resource](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-open-resource.htm)
- IntelliJ IDEA [Navigate to *](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)
- Sublime Text [Go to anything](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-public-alpha)

Comment: There is not 1 way to implement fuzzy search. Your requirements are much too vague to come up with a proper answer.

Comment: `*l*i*k*e*t*h*i*s*` ... but i do worry about efficiency of this solution

Comment: @popovitsj User types anything and if it matches some part of the name it shows the result.

Comment: If it's that simple than @Selvin is right, but that's hardly useful. It will give a lot of 'unexpected' matches from the user's perspective.

Comment: If that's a requirement you should edit it into your question.

Comment: @popovitsj if you know a better strategy then please put it as an answer (without re-implementing FTS3 in Java), I'm open to anything that's better than case insensitive "prefix/contains" matching.

Comment: well, i think that there is no build-in rank function ... it is hard to add new functions to SQLite on android(the only way is to recompile - like sqlcipher)

Comment: You can use sim metric for fuzzy search, useful for limited numbers of entry Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

Comment: Did you find a solution/answer to this?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage see my new answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite's FTS allows searches only for entire words, or for word prefixes.

There is no built-in functionality for fuzzy searches like this.
(And the Android database API does not allow you to add custom virtual table implementations.)

Comment: Any idea for alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I went with relaxing my criteria to search all word beginnings:

```
private static String fixQuery(String query) {
    return query.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "*") + "*";
}
```

it works pretty well. Not typo-resistant, but it feels natural when I'm using it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what this does?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage "search all word beginnings", `\\s+` regex means "any contiguous whitespace" so `ab cd    ef` will become `ab*cd*ef*` and [see the docs what `*` means](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#termprefix)

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what an article of a Python-implemented fuzzy search does. I'm using Laravel, and found I could simply use scope queries for this. If that doesn't work, I'll come back to your solution. THank you.

Comment: I think * can only appear at the end of search term it can't appear in the middle

Comment: @MohammadYahia I know it works in the middle as well, I'm using this in my inventory app: `fixQuery("but saf") -> "but*saf*"` matches *"Random Buttons and Safety Pins"*.