# FTS4 query's error in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, fts4

I create a fts4 table on PC using:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE main USING fts4(word, definition, notindexed=definition);
```

In SQLite Studio i queried a statement, which ran ok:

```
SELECT rowid AS _id, word, definition FROM main WHERE word MATCH 'はな*';
```

When i extracted the database to use in my Android app, the same query give out following error:

```
03-27 11:22:05.315    6789-6789/com.kradragon.minadictionary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized parameter: notindexed=definition (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT rowid AS _id, word, definition FROM main WHERE word MATCH 'はな*';
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:886)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:497)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.model.DictDatabaseHelper.queryWordsMatch(DictDatabaseHelper.java:40)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.model.DictionaryManager.findWordsMatch(DictionaryManager.java:43)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.ResultsListFragment$WordListCursorLoader.loadCursor(ResultsListFragment.java:141)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.model.SqliteCursorLoader.loadInBackground(SqliteCursorLoader.java:24)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.ResultsListFragment.queryWords(ResultsListFragment.java:47)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.MainActivity.handleIntent(MainActivity.java:134)
            at com.kradragon.minadictionary.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2486)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1435)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I read about `notindexed` in [here](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_5)

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTS `notindexed` option was added in [SQLite 3.8.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_0.html), which is not the [version of SQLite used in most Androids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).