# Same SQLite Query doesnot run in all the android version

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-version

I am executing the following query in the SQLite :

```
SELECT * from ValueTable where SrNo = (with t as(SELECT SrNo,Value2 from ValueTable where Value2<'600' ) SELECT SrNo from t order by Value2 DESC limit 1)
```

The table schema is

```
SrNo   Value1   Value2

 1       200     450

 2       500     350

 3       100     500
```

So whenever I run the above query in my code, it works fine with the lollipop version. But gives error when run on the lower versions. I have no clue why. It gives the error near the 't' in the query above. What exactly am I missing ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT :
Here's the error log :

```
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "t": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from ValueTable where SrNo = (with t as(SELECT SrNo,Value2 from ValueTable where Value2<'600' ) SELECT SrNo from t order by Value2 DESC limit 1)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
            at kunal.trial.trialsqliteinallversions.TestAdapter.getTestData(TestAdapter.java:56)
            at kunal.trial.trialsqliteinallversions.MainActivity.LoadEmployee(MainActivity.java:54)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: not very familiar with the `with` clause, but if you're using it as in here - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html , it seems youc an only use it with the recursive / ordinary statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WITH` clause support was added in [SQLite 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3).

API levels below 20 are using an [older version of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Refactor your query that you get the results you want with the SQL supported on all targeted API levels.

Comment: Thank you.. Just to get the direction right - was there any alternative available in the earlier version for 'with clause' or do I have to think the whole different way to implement the above query ?

Comment: Before that one would do recursive queries with the help of a programming language. I didn't read your SQL so much that I could say if you could achieve the same without recursion.