# android studio FTS4 Select statement in ADB using MATCH

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a SQLITE3 database in DB Browser for SQLITE and ran 
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE recinfo USING fts4(content='Listing', Company) to create FTS4 database.
Loaded the database to an android app but unable to run a full text select statement successfully from within the app, so tried ADB in an emulator using the latest versions of Android Studio and SDK.
If I go to ADB I can see all relevant tables (inc FTS4 tables) and if I use
Select * from recinfo;   I get the full list of records displayed.
However if I try,   select * from recinfo where recinfo match 'ab*';  I get nothing.  I have tried many combinations of the prefix full index search with no success.
The fts4 table is a single columned text table circa 500 records, to become 90,000 records when fully developed.
I have successfully used SQLITE3 as a standard database but database size has moved me down the FTS4 route which is new to me and I was trying to keep the use simple.
Does Android Studio support full text index prefix searches?
Any advice appreciated

Comment: Which version of Android did you use? FTS4 supported not on all versions

Answer (score 0):

FTS4 was [added in SQLite 3.7.4](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_1).

Android guarantee [version 3.4.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) according to documentation. Some devices ships with newer version according to [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/4002895)

Sqlite 3.7.4 available on most devices since Android 3.0 Honeycomb and higher.

You can check actual version using `adb shell sqlite3 --version` command on emulator.

Or using this code:

```
Cursor cursor = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(":memory:", null).rawQuery("select sqlite_version() AS sqlite_version", null);
String sqliteVersion = "";
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
   sqliteVersion += cursor.getString(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response, I did check version which is sqlite3  3.8.6. and using android studio 1.2.2.  I  am offline for 14 hrs now , long haul flight but please leave any further info and I will check tomorrow.  Has anyone else succeeded in using fts4?.

Comment: Still struggling to get this to work as a complex query.

Comment: Maybe you must try FTS3 ?

Comment: I have tried both FTS3 and FTS4 and both work if you use the insert command but I have 90,000 rows.   I think it may be my use of  'content' as I cannot get anything reported from within DB Browser for SQLite having created the FTS3 or FTS4 tables in that application.

Comment: sorry was going to add, using DB Browser for SQLite also cut out anything to do with android.