# How to reuse a table with UNION?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to reuse a table in SQLite.  My attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Partials.e_sentence
FROM
        (SELECT 
            e_sentence, _id
        FROM 
            Pair 
                JOIN PairCategories
                    ON
                        _id=PairId AND CategoryId=53

        UNION

        SELECT 
            e_sentence, _id
        FROM 
            Pair
        WHERE
            e_sentence LIKE '%' || 'how often' || '%'
        GROUP BY 
            e_sentence)
    AS Parents JOIN Partials
        ON Parents._id=ParentId

UNION

SELECT
    e_sentence
FROM
    Parents
```

**The key part I am trying to accomplish is at the bottom,** where I try to UNION a table created in the previous statement.  Is there a way to do this in SQLite, or am I forced to repeat the query that made the Parents table in the first half of the UNION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH Parents AS (
    SELECT e_sentence, _id
    FROM Pair
    JOIN PairCategories
    ...
)
SELECT Partials.e_sentence
FROM Parents
JOIN Partials ON Parents._id = ParentId
UNION
SELECT e_sentence
FROM Parents;
```

If you're using an older SQLite (probably because you're using an [older Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)), you can create a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) for the subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW Parents AS
    SELECT e_sentence, _id
    FROM Pair
    JOIN PairCategories
    ...;

SELECT Partials.e_sentence
FROM Parents
JOIN Partials ON Parents._id = ParentId
UNION
SELECT e_sentence
FROM Parents;
```

If you do not want to have this view permanently in the database, you could make it temporary (`CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW ...`) so that it is not available outside the current database connection, or, as last resort, you could just insert the subquery wherever you would use `Parent`:

```
SELECT Partials.e_sentence
FROM (SELECT ...) AS Parents
JOIN Partials ON Parents._id = ParentId
UNION
SELECT e_sentence
FROM (SELECT ...) AS Parents;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  I wish I could award you more points as you've saved me a lot of headbanging. It's a shame StackOverflow's reward system favors simple and easy answers as opposed to well thought out and time-involved ones such as this :)