# Converting MySQL query to SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I got the following MySQL query which I need to convert to a SQLite query (to use in my android application)

```
select *
from msgsList
where (least(msg_from, msg_to), greatest(msg_from, msg_to), msg_time)       
in 
(
    select 
       least(msg_from, msg_to) as x, greatest(msg_from, msg_to) as y, 
       max(msg_time) as msg_time
    from msgsList 
    group by x, y
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, LEAST()/GREATEST() are just called MIN()/MAX().

SQLite does not support IN with tuples, but you can join the table to the subquery instead:

```
SELECT msgsList.*
FROM msgsList
JOIN (SELECT MIN(msg_from, msg_to) AS x,
             MAX(msg_from, msg_to) AS y,
             MAX(msg_time) AS msg_time
     FROM msgsList
     GROUP BY x, y) AS m
ON m.x        = MIN(msgsList.msg_from, msgsList.msg_to) AND
   m.y        = MAX(msgsList.msg_from, msgsList.msg_to) AND
   m.msg_time = msgsList.msg_time;
```

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later (which is [not available in all Android versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)), you can simply use the aggregate MAX() to select the rows to return:

```
SELECT *,
       MAX(msg_time)
FROM msgsList
GROUP BY MIN(msg_from, msg_to),
         MAX(msg_from, msg_to);
```

Comment: Wonderfull, you are awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rawQuery(String query)` of SQLiteDatabse class to run as it is.

Comment: SQLite does not have LEAST()/GREATEST() or IN on tuples.

Comment: I know, but this is a MySQL query, which isn't SQLite right?

Comment: Im not sure, but couldnt you just use max instead of greatest and min instead of meast? Of course i mean the multi-argument max function.
So something like that: min(msg_from, msg_to) ?

Comment: @JoshuadV true, I tried, however I also use several SELECT queries inside one, so I assume that would give some problems too?