# Why do I get syntax error when creating a view with column names?

Tags: android, sqlite

Developing an Android app, but this is a SQLite question.... My SQL is much ropier than my Java.

This is the SQL (copied from a log file, in code it's constructed from various constants):

```
CREATE VIEW albums (_id, name , type ) AS SELECT rowno, name, subtype   FROM metadata WHERE subtype = 'album'
```

but it throws:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
```

Specifying column names in the view seems to me to be clearly permitted, if I understand the flow chart in the sqlite documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html), and at this time of night I really can't see what's wrong. I have tried changing the name of the _id column in case it was something to do with the initial underscore, but to no avail and in any case I will need the _id column later for the CursorAdapter that will end up using this View.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the documentation page you linked it states:

> Note that the column-name list syntax is only supported in SQLite
>   versions 3.9.0 and later.

Version 3.9.0 is not supported by Android.  [Lollipop has 3.7.11.  Marshmallow has 3.8.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Comment: Thank you.  I feared that might be the case but I was looking in all the wrong places.