# Android sqlite query with a WITH clause?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-database

On Android, is there any way that I can execute a raw `android.database.sqlite` query that starts with a WITH clause such as: `WITH one(x) AS (SELECT 1) SELECT x FROM one;`?

The following fragment gives me a syntax error message (in my main activity code):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog ad = b.create();

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor c;

    try {
        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.db", 0, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ad.setMessage("Could not open database: " + e.toString());
        ad.show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("WITH one(x) AS (SELECT 1) SELECT x FROM one;", new String[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ad.setMessage("Could not execute query: " + e.toString());
        ad.show();
        return;
    }

    if (c == null)
        ad.setMessage("Got null query result");
    else
        ad.setMessage("Got valid query result");

    ad.show();
```

It works if I replace the `db.rawQuery` statement with:

```
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT 1;", new String[0]);
```

UPDATE 1 (edited): The **same** `WITH one(x) AS (SELECT 1) SELECT x FROM one;` statement **works** for me in the following:

- sqlite3 CLI
- within a Web SQL transaction on <s>Android and</s> iOS *(iOS 9.2, not 8.0)*
- in the iOS version of https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage *(iOS 9.2, not 8.0)*.

Comment: You have named your column "1" so the "SELECT x FROM one" will fail because there is no column named X

Comment: "SELECT 1" returns the results of executing the "1" expression, which is simply 1. In the query, the "x" means return the results of the one(x) function (with no value specified for "x" which is OK in this case). For reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: This WITH ... SELECT statement seems to work on 3.8.5 (and later), _not_ on 3.7.x (or earlier). I will next try it with SQLCipher 3.4.0 for Android, which is based on SQLite 3.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Android sqlite database may be too old to support this query. The following Android sqlite database libraries will support this query (*tested*):

- https://github.com/liteglue/Android-sqlite-connector
- https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

In addition, some newer versions of Android may have updated sqlite. For reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/1283667 (accepted answer to [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android))
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58909
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191289

Answer (score 0):

The WITH syntax were introduced only recently in sqlite version 3.8.3.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

So you check version sqlite using