# Why this patrially non-aggregated group-by works?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Any idea why the following two queries produce the same results? According to all references I've seen, the first shouldn't even work, but it does. Obviously, if its not a glitch, I prefer the first as it's a simpler and probably faster query.

```
SELECT *,MIN(ts) FROM tbl GROUP BY id;

SELECT *,ts FROM tbl a WHERE rowid IN 
     (SELECT rowid FROM tbl b WHERE a.id = b.id ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1);
```

Here's some sample data:

```
rowid   id  ts  name
    1   58  10  aaa
    2   58   5  bbb
    3   72   7  ccc
```

result expected:

```
    2   58   5  bbb  5     
    3   72   7  ccc  7
```

[SQLFiddle here...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/459ae/2)

Comment: It would be useful to see what the data you're querying looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is guaranteed to work since SQLite [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html).

As for the why: some paying customer wanted it ...

Comment: So according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/3766649), only supported on android versions 4.1+. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works because some platforms that don't support windowing functions treat this construct as a windowing function -- on SQL Server, Oracle and db2 you would have to write

```
 min(ts) over(order by ts)
```