# Can I rely on using the SQLite's built in functions in my Android eviroment?

Tags: android, c, sqlite

I came accross a Exception with two devices a Honeywell CT50 and a Zebra TC75. Both running on a 4.x android version where I tried to use the `printf` SQLite function.

The exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: printf (code 1): , while compiling: xxx

The related query:

```
SELECT 
  rowid, 
  printf('GPS;%s;%f;%f;%f;%f', Timestamp, Longitude, Latitude, Speed, Bearing) 
FROM CapturedLocation;
```

On different Devices e.g. Nexus, Galaxy, Sony, Opticon everything works as intended.

Basically I wonder if I can rely on using SQLite functions and that they are implemented as stated in the offical SQLite documentation or if it's manufacturer specific and I have to hope that Manufacturers implement SQLite completely.

In my current implementation I handle the exception with a try/catch block but I wonder if there are any other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sqlite `printf` was added in [version 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_3) and many [platform versions have older version of sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Consider formatting the output in your application code rather than in SQL.