# Virtual Table using fts4 not getting created android

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I am trying to create a virtual table using `fts4` with external content table. The app works fine on `API 23` but when I ran it on `API 16` it crashed.

Create statement :

```
String DDL_FTS_TODO_TABLE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "+TBL_VIRTUAL_TODO+" USING fts4(content=\""+TBL_TODO+"\", "+
COL_TODO_TITLE +", "+COL_TODO_TITLE +", "+COL_TODO_DUE_DATE+"," +COL_TODO_ALARMDATE+","+ COL_TODO_REPEAT+", "+COL_TODO_LIST_ID+")";
```

My logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.recyclerviewtest/com.example.recyclerviewtest.HomeActivity}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: vtable constructor failed: virtual_todo (code 1)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: vtable constructor failed: virtual_todo (code 1)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:738)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1602)
at com.example.recyclerviewtest.database.TodoOpenHelper.onCreate(TodoOpenHelper.java:32)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
at com.example.recyclerviewtest.database.TodoContentProvider.query(TodoContentProvider.java:52)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
at com.example.recyclerviewtest.database.TodoDbHelper.getAllLists(TodoDbHelper.java:123)
at com.example.recyclerviewtest.HomeActivity.onResume(HomeActivity.java:110)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2586)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: SQLite versions vary by Android OS release. It may be that this feature is not available on the older SQLite versions, or that you are tripping over some bug that was fixed in newer SQLite versions.

Comment: But according to [Android Sqlite version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) API 16 supports fts4

Comment: But perhaps `content=` is a newer feature.

Comment: It is indeed a new feature but API 16 has the sqlite that fully support the `content` option

Comment: There is a mistake in the create statement...It has a same column added twice. Because of this the app was crashing on real device. Apologies for silly question