# Not in operator not working with unique index

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In my android application I am trying to create unique index in on upgrade in my table but I want to exclude some duplicate ids which are previously created so I have created sql query like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexname ON tblName(formid, formno) WHERE ID NOT IN (36, 37)
```

but it give me error

```
09-21 19:15:51.378: W/System.err(31454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {a.b.c/a.b.c.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexname ON tblName(formid, formno) WHERE ID NOT IN (36, 37)
```

Data type of id is integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Partial indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) are supported since SQLite [3.8.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_0.html).

This would be [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) only in Android API level 21 (Lollipop) or higher.