# cast as interger in sqlite android not returning accurate result

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to use `CAST AS INTEGER` in `WHERE` clause. Since I have a column as `TEXT` and I want to apply `<=` and `>=` on that column. It is working well (fine records as excpetectd i,e 12 records) on `SqlBrowser` but not returning accurate resutls (cast as integer seems like not working more than 1000 records) on emulator or device (its  `SqlLite` Database ). Here is my query

```
SELECT  l.* FROM leads AS l   
WHERE cast ( l.lead_budget  as INTEGER)  >=  1200
AND  cast ( l.lead_budget as INTEGER ) <=  15000
```

I m wondering what Am I missing. Any guess

Comment: which android version are you using ?

Comment: I am trying on android 4.4

Comment: How is it "not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check the edited question.

Comment: i had this issue once. the problem was with sqlite version of kitkat. try this on greater version of android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with `kitkat`. I had such issue in past. I tried same cast query on 6.0 and it was working as expected. Try it on 6.0 .
But `sqllite` supports casting and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) is it's documentation about cast as integer etc.
But after a little more digging I found that most kitkat uses `SQLite 3.7.11:` .[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) is a link.
I found this [page](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) about versions of sqllite. They describe the issue they fixed in each version.

### This is what they changed in 3.8.2

Changed the defined behavior for the CAST expression when floating point values greater than `+9223372036854775807` are cast into into integers so that the result is the largest possible integer, `+9223372036854775807`, instead of the smallest possible integer, `-9223372036854775808`. After this change, CAST(9223372036854775809.0 as INT) yields `+9223372036854775807` instead of `-9223372036854775808`. ← **Potentially Incompatible Change!**

And then in `3.8.7` They improve optimization of CAST operators. And then I found this [ticket](http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/689137afb6da41) which explain alot of what's really wrong. Now it's fixed might work or new device but with older devices you have to find some other solution. With this os issue,  you cannot rely on cast query. Since you are not sure about which os version uses which SQL version. Hope it helps.