# "WITH" clause Query not working in android

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my rawQuery

```
WITH authorRating(aname, rating) AS SELECT aname, AVG(quantity) FROM book GROUP BY aname
```

error is in Logcate

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WITH": syntax error (code 1):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WITH is supported since SQLite 3.8.3, and that is not [shipped with all Android versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Anyway, this query is not a [valid WITH clause](http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/with-clause.html), and lacks the actual query.

Comment: Thanks you, you save from me from lots of troubles.i was think that there was error in my code,but now its fine all the things.its works on Android Api level 20 and above. thank you.