# Sqlite CorruptDatabaseException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, android-sqlite, root

I copy database from other app package in Download folder, i do it by root and terminal commands. I have permissions on external storage, But when i try to open database, i have that exception, how to fix that ? If try to open database on desktop, all ok.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: malformed database 
    schema (part_idx_MESSAGES_LIKES_read_0) - near "WHERE": syntax error (code 11): 
    , while compiling: select name from sqlite_master where type='table'
```

Comment: I am not sure about the corruption, but a work around could be to dump the schema and data from the original database into a textfile and then run the scripts on the new database location. Helpful explanantion at: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/

Answer (score 0):

The database uses features introduces in a recent SQLite version (probably an [expression index](http://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html)), and the SQLite library on Android [is too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on @CL's post, but I do not have enough reputation so I will add as an answer and it may get moved. Anyway, assuming @CL is right, and I think he is, my suggestion below the question of a work around using a schema and data dump would be a way to transfer between the different versions. I hope it helps.