# Can I index first n char of a column in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Official docs don't throw any light on this. I want to index first n char on my column to save memory space. Is it even possible with sqlite? If so, How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can index a complete column

Answer (score 0):

You can put an [index on an expression](http://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html):

```
CREATE INDEX xxx ON MyTable(substr(MyColumn, 1, 10));
```

This index will be used only when a query expression matches the index expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE substr(MyColumn, 1, 10) = ?;
```

---

This feature requires SQLite 3.9 or later, which [is available only in Android 7 ("Nougat") or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).