# SQLite Syntax error while compiling: INSERT INTO

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, runtimeexception

I'm getting this RuntimeException when executing an AsyncTask:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO 'infrastructure' (lift,name,type,status,_id) VALUES ('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',0),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',1),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',2),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',3),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',4),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',5)
```

All columns except _id are "text", _id is an integer and primary key.

This is where it crashes:

```
Cursor curtsr = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'Infrastructure'", null);
if (curtsr != null) {
    curtsr.moveToFirst();                      // Always one row returned.
    if (curtsr.getInt(0) == 0) {               // Zero count means empty table.
        String INSERT_INFRA_VALUES = "INSERT INTO 'Infrastructure' (lift,name,type,status,_id) VALUES ('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',0),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',1),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',2),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',3),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',4),('2130837612','none','-','2130837600',5)";
        db.execSQL(INSERT_INFRA_VALUES);
    }
    curtsr.close();
}
```

I can't find the reason why it's crashing.

Online SQLite lint tool https://sqliteonline.com/ isn't throwing any errors.

Comment: Do not use single quotes for table and column names.  I vote to close such questions as simple typographical errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff removing the quotes from the table name doesn't change a single thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comma-separated multiple `VALUES` insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) was only introduced in sqlite 3.7.11 and chances are you are running on a [device with older sqlite version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android).

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. I'm using API level 15. 

3.7.11 is for API 16+