# How to replace instr() function in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Given that **`instr()`** function isn't supported in SQLite KitKat Android how can I obtain following expression in a SQL statement?

```
substr(mystring, instr(mystring, '_')+1)
```

My target is to get first part of a string until **'_'** where its position is variable. I use this expression in a `JOIN` clause and I need it directly in **`SQL`**.

Thanks in advance.
Danilo

Comment: "Given that instr() function isn't supported in SQLite KitKat" source? This https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr says instr is in sqlite, and I haven't found any indication that kitkat would not have it

Comment: @njzk2 added **2012-12-12 (3.7.15)** as per [http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_15](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_15)

Comment: @MikeT Thanks. Together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android it confirms that kitkat does not have `instr` function

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the best/ideal/mot elegant way, but you could use something based upon the following :-

```
-- Create testing Table and data
--CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noinstr (test TEXT);
--INSERT INTO noinstr VALUES('short_xxx');
--INSERT INTO noinstr VALUES('thisisevenlonger_yyyyyyyy');
--INSERT INTO noinstr VALUES('nothing to return in this text');
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN substr(test,2,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,1)
    WHEN substr(test,3,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,2)
    WHEN substr(test,4,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,3)
    WHEN substr(test,5,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,4)
    WHEN substr(test,6,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,5)
    WHEN substr(test,7,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,6)
    WHEN substr(test,8,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,7)
    WHEN substr(test,9,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,8)
    WHEN substr(test,10,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,9)
    WHEN substr(test,11,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,10)
    WHEN substr(test,12,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,11)
    WHEN substr(test,13,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,12)
    WHEN substr(test,14,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,13)
    WHEN substr(test,15,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,14)
    WHEN substr(test,16,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,15)
    WHEN substr(test,17,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,16)
    WHEN substr(test,18,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,17)
    --- More as required
    ELSE ''
END AS result
FROM noinstr
```

The initial commented out statements create the table **noinstr** with a single column name **test** and populate the table with 3 rows as per :-

[image]

The query returns :-

[image]

### EDIT re comment :-

> This "search and test" approach seem a little bit convoluted but it
>   works. But what if string is too much long? You have to hard code the
>   test for all possible character position

You could always generate the SQL based upon the maximum length e.g. :-

```
public String buildCaseClause(String coretable,
                              String corecolumn,
                              String mvcolumn,
                              String separator,
                              String resultcolumn ) {
    long maxstrlen = 0;

    // Get maximun length of Data
    Cursor mv = mDB.query(
            coretable,
            new String[]{"max(length(" + corecolumn + ")) AS " + mvcolumn},
            null,null,null,null,null
    );
    if(mv.moveToFirst()) {
        maxstrlen = mv.getLong(mv.getColumnIndex(mvcolumn));
    }
    mv.close();

    // If max string length is less than 2 then return an empty string
    if (maxstrlen < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    //WHEN substr(test,2,1) = '_' THEN substr(test,1,1)
    StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder(" CASE");
    for (int i=2;i <= maxstrlen;i++) {
        rv.append(
                " WHEN substr(" +
                        corecolumn+
                        "," + String.valueOf(i) +
                ",1) = '" + separator +
                "' THEN substr(" +
                        corecolumn +
                        ",1," + String.valueOf(i-1) + ")");
    }
    // Add
    rv.append(" ELSE '' END AS " + resultcolumn);
    return rv.toString();
}
```

This could then be called like :-

```
public Cursor getSplitDataPart() {
    return mDB.query(TBNOINSTR,
            new String[]{"*",buildCaseClause(TBNOINSTR,COL_TBNOINSTR_DATA,"mv","_", "result")},
            null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Which could itself be used like :-

```
    SO48879002DBHlpr dbhlpr = new SO48879002DBHlpr(this);
    // Add some testing data
    dbhlpr.addData("short_secondpart");
    dbhlpr.addData("thisislonger_secondpart");
    dbhlpr.addData("thisisanevenlongerfirstdatapart_secondaprt");
    // Log the generated SQL that could be incoporated
    Log.d("SPLIDATASQL",dbhlpr.buildCaseClause(SO48879002DBHlpr.TBNOINSTR,SO48879002DBHlpr.COL_TBNOINSTR_DATA,"mv","_","result"));
    // Extract the data into a cursor
    Cursor csr = dbhlpr.getSplitDataPart();
    // Log the results
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Extracted First Datapart is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("result")));
    }
```

- SO48879002DBHlpr being the DatabaseHelper (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper)
- the buildCaseClause could be private, however for testing it wa made public thus facilitating the use of  `Log.d("SPLIDATASQL",dbhlpr.buildCaseClause(SO48879002DBHlpr.TBNOINSTR,SO48879002DBHlpr.COL_TBNOINSTR_DATA,"mv","_","result"));` for testing.
- TB_NOINSTR is the table name , COl_TBNOINSTR_DATA is the co-joined data.

In this case the resultant log includes :-

```
02-21 20:14:01.623 1690-1690/? D/SPLIDATASQL:  CASE WHEN substr(_data,2,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,1) WHEN substr(_data,3,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,2) WHEN substr(_data,4,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,3) WHEN substr(_data,5,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,4) WHEN substr(_data,6,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,5) WHEN substr(_data,7,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,6) WHEN substr(_data,8,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,7) WHEN substr(_data,9,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,8) WHEN substr(_data,10,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,9) WHEN substr(_data,11,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,10) WHEN substr(_data,12,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,11) WHEN substr(_data,13,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,12) WHEN substr(_data,14,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,13) WHEN substr(_data,15,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,14) WHEN substr(_data,16,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,15) WHEN substr(_data,17,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,16) WHEN substr(_data,18,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,17) WHEN substr(_data,19,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,18) WHEN substr(_data,20,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,19) WHEN substr(_data,21,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,20) WHEN substr(_data,22,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,21) WHEN substr(_data,23,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,22) WHEN substr(_data,24,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,23) WHEN substr(_data,25,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,24) WHEN substr(_data,26,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,25) WHEN substr(_data,27,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,26) WHEN substr(_data,28,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,27) WHEN substr(_data,29,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,28) WHEN substr(_data,30,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,29) WHEN substr(_data,31,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,30) WHEN substr(_data,32,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,31) WHEN substr(_data,33,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,32) WHEN substr(_data,34,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,33) WHEN substr(_data,35,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,34) WHEN substr(_data,36,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,35) WHEN substr(_data,37,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,36) WHEN substr(_data,38,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,37) WHEN substr(_data,39,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,38) WHEN substr(_data,40,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,39) WHEN substr(_data,41,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,40) WHEN substr(_data,42,1) = '_' THEN substr(_data,1,41) ELSE '' END AS result
02-21 20:14:01.627 1690-1690/? D/DBINFO: Extracted First Datapart is short
02-21 20:14:01.627 1690-1690/? D/DBINFO: Extracted First Datapart is thisislonger
02-21 20:14:01.627 1690-1690/? D/DBINFO: Extracted First Datapart is thisisanevenlongerfirstdatapart
```

Comment: This "search and test" approach seem a little bit convoluted
but it works. But what if string is too much long? You have to hard code the test for all possible character position

Comment: @Danilo.NET the real convolution is the design, if well designed distinct columns would be utilised.