# Aggregate functions are not Alloowed in the GROUP BY clause(code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having this following weird issue with Sqlite query in Android 4.4.2 version devices.Thanks in advance

The table structure is as below

```
CREATE TABLE responsemaster (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    formid integer,
    proposerid text,
    fieldid integer,
    response text,
    remarks text,
    listId integer,
    isMarked integer
)
```

and the query that giving error is

```
SELECT id as id, formid as formid, proposerid as proposerid, MIN(fieldid) fieldid, response as response, remarks as remarks, listId as listId, isMarked as isMarked
FROM responsemaster
WHERE formid = 40066 AND proposerid = '7ca6533a-c5f0-43e2-9980-83f9ae2c7370201802230113550000'
GROUP BY fieldid
```

The exception i'm getting is as follows

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause (code 1):, 
while compiling: SELECT id as id, formid as formid, proposerid as proposerid,  **MIN(CAST(fieldid AS INTEGER)) AS fieldid**, response as response, remarks as remarks, listId as listId, isMarked as isMarked FROM responsemaster WHERE formid = 40066 AND proposerid = '7ca6533a-c5f0-43e2-9980-83f9ae2c7370201802230113550000'  GROUP BY fieldid
```

The above query will execute successfully in SQLite browser and in Greater than Android 4.4.2 version devices..Please can any one help me how i can able to fix that error?

Comment: Perhaps support for that was added in SQLite 3.8, as Android 4.4 and older [use older versions of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/115145).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query it may replace the aggregate function

```
SELECT id as id, formid as formid, proposerid as proposerid, fieldid as 
       fieldid, response as response, remarks as remarks, listId as listId, 
       isMarked as isMarked FROM responsemaster WHERE formid = 40066 AND proposerid = '7ca6533a-c5f0-43e2-9980-83f9ae2c7370201802230113550000' 
       GROUP BY fieldid HAVING fieldid = MIN(fieldid)
```

Comment: @Shiva Try the above query. That may help you to avoid aggregate function in group by clause. Add a Having Clause

Comment: Happy to here that .Happy Coding Bro.

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING clause instead of WHERE with AGGREGATE Functions :)
It will solve it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/use-having-and-where-clauses-in-the-same-query-visual-database-tools