# Does sqflite support query with 'CASE WHEN'?

Tags: case-when, sqflite

I try to run a query via sqflite and get the error below:

```
DatabaseException(no such column: true (code 1): , while compiling: select (case true WHEN true THEN 111 END) xkey1 from tb_path
```

Here are the SQL steps:

1. `create table tb_path(name text, age text);`
2. `db.rawQuery('select (case true WHEN true THEN 111 END) xkey1 from tb_path');`
   and the error above showed up.

If I try to run the SQL via SqlLite Expert Personal (a windows version SQLITE tool), this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your steps in sqlite command line (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ select sqlite_version();
3.22.0
$ CREATE TABLE tb_path(from_ text, to_ text);
$ select (case true WHEN true THEN 111 END) xkey1 from tb_path;
Error: no such column: true
```

If I try with the latest binary download (3.27), I don't get the error:

```
$ select sqlite_version();
3.27.2
$ CREATE TABLE tb_path(from_ text, to_ text);
$ select (case true WHEN true THEN 111 END) xkey1 from tb_path;
```

So maybe such statement is only valid for newer sqlite version and since sqflite uses whatever the iOS/Android platform provides, it might not be supported yet (see a good list of shipping sqlite version on Android here: [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android#answer-4377116))