# How to create partial index in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, android-room

I'd like to create a partial index on my table named `Messages` on `State` and `Id` columns. Normally this can be done by adding a `WHERE` clause to create index statement as described in the [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html). The proper SQLite statement would be:

```
CREATE INDEX `index_Messages_State_Id` ON `Messages` (`State`, `Id`) WHERE State = -2
```

Since I'm currently using Room as my ORM, I don't know how to declare a partial index using Room syntax.

Here is a brief of my `Messages` table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Messages")
public class Message implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("i")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Id")
    private long mId;

    @SerializedName("t")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Type")
    private byte mType;

    @SerializedName("s")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "State")
    private byte mState;

    ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a defined way of doing this in Room (as at July 22nd, 2019).

On my team, we got around this blocker by defining the partial index inside a migration.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `index_Messages_State_Id` ON `Messages` (`State`, `Id`) WHERE State = -2")
```

NB: This might not work if your Android version is less than 21. [Partial index only work on SQLite 3.8.0](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html#supported_versions) and above, which is [supported in API >= 21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/7962624)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however declaring the partial index inside a migration seems not helpful for fresh-install users since the migration won't get involved.

Comment: Good point. A way around that would be to run the SQL statement on app startup, using the old Android SQLite functionality. Hacky, but what else to do ‍♂️