# Android.Sqlite not support the RANK() OVER?

Tags: android, sqlite

my sqlite code (include Rank() OVER)  could run in ANY sqlite3，but could NOT RUN in then AVD in the Android Studio.

I tested directly in the AVD's "adb shell", not running too.

and I find the ".dbinfo" command could not run in the android.sqlite too.

even i test the android os from 5 to 10 version, it could not run at all.

is there anything i missed ?

Comment: Window functions support was added in version 3.25.0 of SQLite. You can execute this query: `select sqlite_version();` to get the version that Android uses.

Comment: Based on [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) Android 10 is at 3.22.0

Comment: checked the version by "select sqlite_version();", and the result is [3.8.6.1]

Comment: is there any way to emulate the RANK function?