# Room Databse - Query Error as no viable alternative at input

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using Room in Android and done as below in my dao file :

```
@Query("select DISTINCT timeStamp, batteryId, status " +
            "from (select batteryDetails.*, " +
            "lag(status) over (partition by batteryId order by timeStamp) as oldStatus " +
            "from batteryDetails) batteryDetails " +
            "where status is null or oldStatus <> status")
    suspend fun getHistoryEventsData(): List<BatteryDetailsHistory>?
```

While executing above query, Getting below error :

> error: no viable alternative at input '(select batteryDetails.*, lag(status) over ('
> public abstract java.lang.Object getHistoryEventsData(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
> ^
> extraneous input '(' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

There might be some issue in query syntax.
Please guide.

Comment: the query looks fine

Comment: This query I got from backend. Using it with Android Room database. It's fine?

Comment: @eshirvana Can you please guide me to remove this window functions from the above query and make it simple..

Comment: see forpas answer

Comment: Finally I have deal it with sub query.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of SQLite does not support window functions, you can replace `LAG()` with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT timeStamp, batteryId, status  
FROM (
  SELECT b1.*,  
    (
      SELECT b2.status 
      FROM batteryDetails b2 
      WHERE b2.batteryId = b1.batteryId AND b2.timeStamp < b1.timeStamp 
      ORDER BY b2.timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS oldStatus  
  FROM batteryDetails b1
) 
WHERE status IS NULL OR oldStatus <> status
```

Comment: Finally I have deal it with sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Your version of sqlite doesn't support window functions including `LAG` because android app use build-in version on sqlite library to android OS. That's why version of sqlite depends on android's api level version (where app running). According [to sqlite docs(paragraph 6)](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) the window functions was added in version 3.25.0 and according [to google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary) (and [other answer on stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)the sqlite's window functions supports on android since android api level 30.

To solve the problem of fragmentation of slqlite library you can [use android-requery](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) which allows to use last version of sqlile in all android versions(since API level 14). It's easy to use [this library with room.](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/blob/f63a67898d1c83a257f691e5e9cf7e0c6902045d/README.md#support-library-compatibility)

Comment: Finally I have deal it with sub query.