# Room Database migration crash

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I have an DB migration:

```
val MIGRATION_8_9 = object : Migration(8, 9) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE RideEntity RENAME frontVideoPresent TO frontVideoState")
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE RideEntity RENAME rearVideoPresent TO rearVideoState")
  }
}
```

When testing this migration on local Samsung phones it worked fine. The in production with help of craslytics I seen this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Exception while computing database live data.

Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
near "frontVideoPresent": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while 
compiling: ALTER TABLE RideEntity RENAME frontVideoPresent TO frontVideoState, (OS 
error - 11:Try again)
```

This is happened on Huawei Mate 20 phone. How to understand better this crash? This is OS related?
I can not remove the rename now, because many users that updated the app the column renaming worked, but users with Huawei phones may suffer this crash.
I am open to your suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like version of sqlite on some devices doesn't support column renaming because android app use build-in version on sqlite library to android OS. That's why version of sqlite depends on android's api level version (where app running). [According to sqlite release notes](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html) (paragraph 2) the  support for renaming columns was added in version 3.25.0 and [according to google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary) ([and other answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android))the column's renaming on android  supports since android api level 30.

To solve the problem of fragmentation of slqlite library you can use [android-requery](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) which allows to use last version of sqlile in all android versions(since API level 14). It's easy to [use this library with room](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/blob/f63a67898d1c83a257f691e5e9cf7e0c6902045d/README.md#support-library-compatibility).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added "openHelperFactory(RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory())". But how do I adopt the migration? The override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) expects interface SupportSQLiteDatabase from androidx.sqlite.db

Comment: @Dim RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory creates `androidx.sqlite.db. SupportSQLiteDatabase` and migration should be works fine - out of box .

Comment: @Dim Do you have some problems with it ?

Comment: So I just need to add ".openHelperFactory(RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory())" and keep the "import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase"?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dim If my answer helped you to solve your problem , please mark it as accepted .