# Android Api 28 - crash_report=Exception is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-api-levels

I have written the below query which is working fine on Api 29 and 30 but app is crashing on Api 28 only with the following log System.out: crash_report=Exception is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: true (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: update doctor set is_rogspFiled = true where doctor_contactid = 784829
Here is my query. What do I need to change?

```
 query = " update " + TABLE_DOCTOR + " set " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS + " = " + isFiled + " where " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_CONTACTID + " = " + gspid ;
    cursor = sd.getData(query);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        isFiled = true;
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS, isFiled);
        sd.update(Queryclass.TABLE_DOCTOR, contentValues, query);
    }

    cursor.close();
    sd.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of SQLite used in API 28 is 3.22.0 (check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/10498828)), but the constants `true` and `false` were introduced as aliases of `1` and `0` respectively in SQLite in [version 3.23.0](https://sqlite.org/changes.html).

In your statement you must change `isFiled` which returns `true` or `false` to an integer `1` or `0`:

```
query = "update " + TABLE_DOCTOR + " set " +
        Queryclass.DOCTOR_ROGSP_STATUS + " = " + (isFiled ? 1 : 0) + 
        " where " + Queryclass.DOCTOR_CONTACTID + " = " + gspid;
```

But, concatenating parameters to SQL statement is always a bad idea.
You should use the method [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) where you use `?` placeholders to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem be in your manifest you have read and write permissions?

See if the database is created in this version.

GL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).