# SqlDelight/SQLite How to return type for update/insert/delete

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, sqldelight

How can I return results when using delete/update/insert? I saw on the issues that using RETURNING is suggested, but it doesn't work.

sqldelight 2.0.0

```
CREATE TABLE folder (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

```
insertFolder:
INSERT INTO folder
VALUES (?,?)
RETURNING *;
```

```
Compiling with dialect app.cash.sqldelight.dialects.sqlite_3_18.SqliteDialect

xxx.sq: (21, 0): ',' expected, got 'RETURNING'
19    INSERT INTO folder
20    VALUES (?,?)
21    RETURNING *
      ^^^^^^^^^

Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugDatabaseInterface'.
> A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.SqlDelightTask$GenerateInterfaces
   > Generation failed; see the generator error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I return results when using delete/update/insert?

That will not generally be an option, with framework-supplied SQLite, for many years.

> I saw on the issues that using RETURNING is suggested, but it doesn't work.

`RETURNING` is rather new. As [the SQLite documentation notes](https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html), that keyword is new to "version 3.35.0 (2021-03-12)". According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/115145), the first Android version that ships a new-enough SQLite is Android 14, the version that is being released in 2023.

So, unless your `minSdkVersion` will be 34 or higher, you would need to [package a copy of SQLite with your app](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) and use it. This will add to your app size.

Comment: What should I do in the old version?

Comment: @大盗不操戈: You will need to live without `RETURNING` and live without those operations returning a result.

Comment: If you are using something like sqlcipher, then you are already supporting 3.35.0