# SQlite for Android not working with json_group_array/json_object

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hey all I am trying to get this **SQlite query** to work in my **Android app** but for some reason its giving me the error of:

> no such function: json_object (code 1): , while compiling

But it works in my **DB Browser** when I run the query?

My query is this:

```
SELECT json_group_array( 
    json_object(
        'name', name, 
        'ip', ip,
        'mac', mac,
        'token', token
    )
) 
FROM tvs
```

[image]

And the output is:

> [{"name":"lr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"mbr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"jr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"tr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"dsr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"lr2","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"},
>
> {"name":"lr","ip":"192.168.1.0","mac":"00:00:00:00","token":"na"}]

Putting that query **into my Android app**:

```
Cursor cursor;

try {
   cursor = db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT " +
           "json_group_array(" +
                "json_object(" +
                     "'name', name," +
                     "'ip', ip," +
                     "'mac', mac," +
                     "'token', token" +
                ")" +
           ")" +
      "FROM " +
           "tvs", null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  String result = cursor.getString(0);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The error shows up when on the **db.rawQuery** line.

Does **Androids SQlite** not have support for **json_group_array**/**json_object**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Androids SQlite not have support for json_group_array/json_object?

Based upon

> The JSON functions and operators are built into SQLite by default, as of SQLite version 3.38.0 (2022-02-22).

- https://sqlite.org/json1.html

Then support of the functions would only be for API 34+ (Version 14 or U) according to [Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)

Android versions of the built-in SQLite are historically behind the available versions of SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that for me Mike. Sadly my max Android version is 23 which only supports SQlite 3.8.10.2.